# Display only three numbers of the total pagination numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to add some pagination numbers in Javascript. I already achieved the pagination, I also can show all the pagination numbers but I would like to show only three numbers from all the numbers. Let my show you what I achieved until now:

```
var values = [{name : "a"}, {name : "b"}, {name : "c"}, {name : "d"}, {name : "e"}, {name : "f"}, {name : "g"}, {name : "h"}, {name : "i"}, {name : "j"}];  
var current_page = 1;
var records_per_page = 6;

if (values.length <= 6) {
    btn_prev.style.display = "none";
    btn_next.style.display = "none";
}

function prevPage() {
    if (current_page > 1) {
        current_page--;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}

function nextPage() {
    if (current_page < numPages()) {
        current_page++;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}

function changePage(page) {
    var btn_next = document.getElementById("btn_next");
    var btn_prev = document.getElementById("btn_prev");
    var listing_table = document.getElementById("poi-cat-id");
    var page_span = document.getElementById("page");
    var pageNum = document.getElementById("pageNum");

    // Validate page
    if (page < 1) page = 1;
    if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

    listing_table.innerHTML = "";
    var href = getRootWebSitePath();
    for (var i = (page - 1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page) && i < values.length; i++) {
        var nametoslug1 = values[i].name;
        var slug1 = convertToSlug(nametoslug1);
        listing_table.innerHTML += '<div class="event-desc"><p>' + values[i].name + '</p></div>';
    }

    
    if (page == 1) {
        btn_prev.style.color = "#404141";
    } else {
        btn_prev.style.visibility = "visible";
        btn_prev.style.color = "#0c518a";
    }

    if (page == numPages()) {
        btn_next.style.color = "#404141";
    } else {
        btn_next.style.visibility = "visible";
        btn_next.style.color = "#0c518a";
    }
    male();
    maen();
}

//this is where I add all the numbers of the pagination
var totnum = numPages();
for (var i = 0; i < numPages() + 2; i++) {
    // We do not want page 0. You could have started with i = 1 too.
    $('#page-num-container').append('<a href="javascript:pagesNr()" class="pageClick">' + (i + 1) + '</a>');
}

======EDIT=====
function newPage(){
   $('.pageClick').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    changePage($(this).index() + 1);
   });
} //when I click the number the pages won't change

function numPages() {
    return Math.ceil(values.length / records_per_page);
}

window.onload = function () {
    changePage(1);
};
```

and this is my html :

```
<div>
    <ul class="content-full" id="poi-cat-id"></ul>
    <div class="pagination-poi-arrows">
        <div class="prev">
            <a href="javascript:prevPage()" id="btn_prev"><img src="~/img/left-arrow-pagination.svg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="page-num-container" id="page-num-container">
        </div>
        <div class="nex">
            <a href="javascript:nextPage()" id="btn_next"><img src="~/img/right-arrow-pagination.svg" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-poi-arrows" id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

Can anybody help would be highly appreciated since I've been stuck with this for a while.

Comment: Could you remove the irrelevant code and make the question clearer?

Comment: ofcourse but I think the function changePage() should be here @pavel I just thought you guys might want to take a look at my pagination I made using javascript. Thats why I put it in here.

Comment: @pavel any idea on how I can approach to this problem of mine?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "show only 3 numbers"? Do you want to show the current page, and the first and last page?

Comment: for example if the current page is 2 I want to show 1 2 3..if the current page is 3 I want to show 2 3 4... and so on. Do you get it now @pavel?

Comment: normally you should open another question for this. In this case, try putting the `onclick="..."` attribute inside the `.pageClick` element when you create it. e.g. <a ... onclick="changePage(i)" ... /></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the adjacent page numbers, then you have to start iterating at `i=current_page` until `i=current_page + 2`.

However, it seems that in your code, you start counting at 1 with your pages. I [advise](https://skillcrush.com/2013/01/17/why-programmers-start-counting-at-zero/) you to start at 0.

Now, back to your code. You need to replace the loop with the following (if you're counting from 1):

```
function updatePagination(page) {
    for (var i = page - 1; i < page + 1; i++) {
        $('#page-num-container').append('<a href="javascript:pagesNr()"     
    class="pageClick">' + (i + 1) + '</a>');
    }
}

// you need to clear the element before you update it
function clearPagination() {
    $('#page-num-container').empty();
}
```

You would call both of these methods at the end of the `changePage()` method.

Comment: yes @a-s this will work as to start but then after I change my page the numbers wont update. Let's say if  current page is 2 and the numbers are 1 2 3 after I co to page 3 the number will stuck as 1 2 3 and won't update to 2 3 4. Do you get it?

Comment: @Pavel Oh yes I see, you need to update the `#page-num-container` every time you change the page

Comment: And how can I do that? If I tut this for loop inside the changePage() function the append method will duplicate the numbers. @a-s

Comment: @Pavel I updated the answer. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: hey @a-s can you please take a look to the edit I made to your answer and to my question, and maybe give me an answer on how I can approach to the problem?? Thanks